# Access data-value in Spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using a datalist in html as below:

```
<input type="text" id="eventName" list="eventname" name="eventname" 
    placeholder="Event category">

    <datalist id="eventname">
        <c:forEach var="eventName2" items="${listDropDown}">
           <option  data-id="${eventName2.eventId}" 
               value="${eventName2.eventName}">
        </c:forEach>
    </datalist>
```

I call the value from spring controller using `name` attribute of input field. But i get the `value` attribute of `option` tag.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchForVenues", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public ModelAndView saveProductInfo(ModelAndView model,@RequestParam("eventname")int eventid) {
         System.out.println(eventid);//some code//
     }
```

Output is an exception :

```
Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [int]; 
 nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: 
 "Wedding"
```

Some more HTML :

```
  <div class="col-md-10">
                     <form:form id="signup" action="searchForVenues"  
     method="post" modelAttribute="searchForVenue" >
                         <form:hidden path="id"></form:hidden>
                    <div class="col-md-3"> 
                        <div class="form-group ">



<%--
                    <form:select id="eventName" class="form-control  
        select2" style="width: 100%; -webkit-appearance: none;" 
       path="eventName" multiple="multiple" >
                         <form:option value="0" selected="selected">Select a 
          category</form:option>
                <c:forEach var="eventName2" items="${listDropDown}">
                <form:option  
           value="${eventName2.eventName}">${eventName2.eventName}
         </form:option>
                </c:forEach>
            </form:select> 
                    --%> 

                        <input type="text" id="eventName" list="eventname"  
            placeholder="Event category" >

                        <datalist id="eventname">

                            <c:forEach var="eventName2" 
                items="${listDropDown}">

                                <option  data-id="${eventName2.eventId}" 
                  value="${eventName2.eventName}" >
                                    <input type="hidden" name="eventnames" 
                   id="eventName-hidden" value="${eventName2.eventId}">
                    </c:forEach>
                        </datalist>
                        <input type="hidden" name="eventnames" id="eventName-hidden" value="${eventName2.eventId}">
              </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group ">

                            <%--
                        <form:select id="locationName"  class="form-control select2" path="locationName" multiple="multiple">
                             <form:option value="0" selected="selected">Select a location</form:option>
                    <c:forEach var="locationName" items="${dropdownForLocation}">
                    <form:option  value="${locationName.locName}">${locationName.locName}</form:option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </form:select>
                            --%>

                            <input type="text" id="locationName" list="location" placeholder="Location" name="locationname">
                        <datalist id="location">

                            <c:forEach var="locationName" items="${dropdownForLocation}">
                    <option  data-id="${locationName.locId}">${locationName.locName}</option>
                    <input type="hidden" name="locnames" id="locationName-hidden" value="${locationName.locId}">
                    </c:forEach>
                        </datalist>  
              </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <%--
                        <form:select id="venueTypeName" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" path="venueTypeName">
                            <form:option value="0" selected="selected">Select type of venue</form:option>
                    <c:forEach var="venueTypeName" items="${dropdownForVenueType}">
                    <form:option  value="${venueTypeName.venueTypeName}">${venueTypeName.venueTypeName}</form:option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </form:select>
                            --%>
                            <input type="text" id="venueTypeName" list="venueType" placeholder="Venue type" name="venuetypename"/>
                        <datalist id="venueType" >

                            <c:forEach var="venueTypeName" items="${dropdownForVenueType}">
                                <option  data-id="${venueTypeName.venueTypeId}">${venueTypeName.venueTypeName}</option>
                                <input type="hidden" name="venuenames" id="venueTypeName-hidden" value="${venueTypeName.venueTypeId}">
                    </c:forEach>
                        </datalist>     


              </div>

                    </div >
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn-info" value="Find" id="findbtnn"/>
                    </div>
               </form:form>

                </div>
```

rendered html :

```
 <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->


    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">

      <!-- Default box -->
      <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
<!--          //<h3 class="box-title">Title</h3>-->

          <div class="box-tools pull-right">
<!--            <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse">
              <i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove">
              <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>-->
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                     <form id="signup" action="searchForVenues" method="post">
                         <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="0"/>
                    <div class="col-md-3"> 
                        <div class="form-group ">



                        <input type="text" id="eventName" list="eventname"  placeholder="Event category" >

                        <datalist id="eventname">



                                <option  data-id="1" value="Wedding">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="eventnames" id="eventName-hidden" value="1">


                                <option  data-id="2" value="Birthday">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="eventnames" id="eventName-hidden" value="2">


                                <option  data-id="3" value="Bouvat">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="eventnames" id="eventName-hidden" value="3">


                                <option  data-id="4" value="Akd">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="eventnames" id="eventName-hidden" value="4">


                                <option  data-id="5" value="Khatna">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="eventnames" id="eventName-hidden" value="5">


                                <option  data-id="6" value="Normal Party">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="eventnames" id="eventName-hidden" value="6">

                        </datalist>
                        <input type="hidden" name="eventnames" id="eventName-hidden" value="">
              </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group ">



                            <input type="text" id="locationName" list="location" placeholder="Location" name="locationname">
                        <datalist id="location">


                    <option  data-id="1">Dhanmondi</option>
                    <input type="hidden" name="locnames" id="locationName-hidden" value="1">

                    <option  data-id="2">Gulshan</option>
                    <input type="hidden" name="locnames" id="locationName-hidden" value="2">

                    <option  data-id="3">Shantinagar</option>
                    <input type="hidden" name="locnames" id="locationName-hidden" value="3">

                    <option  data-id="4">Baridhara DOHS</option>
                    <input type="hidden" name="locnames" id="locationName-hidden" value="4">

                    <option  data-id="5">Bashundhara Baridhara</option>
                    <input type="hidden" name="locnames" id="locationName-hidden" value="5">

                    <option  data-id="6">Banani</option>
                    <input type="hidden" name="locnames" id="locationName-hidden" value="6">

                    <option  data-id="7">Paltan</option>
                    <input type="hidden" name="locnames" id="locationName-hidden" value="7">

                        </datalist>  
              </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <input type="text" id="venueTypeName" list="venueType" placeholder="Venue type" name="venuetypename"/>
                        <datalist id="venueType" >


                                <option  data-id="1">Restaurant</option>
                                <input type="hidden" name="venuenames" id="venueTypeName-hidden" value="1">

                                <option  data-id="2">Convention Hall</option>
                                <input type="hidden" name="venuenames" id="venueTypeName-hidden" value="2">

                                <option  data-id="3">Community Center</option>
                                <input type="hidden" name="venuenames" id="venueTypeName-hidden" value="3">

                        </datalist>     


              </div>

                    </div >
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn-info" value="Find" id="findbtnn"/>
                    </div>
               </form>
```

Comment: I think `@RequestParam("eventname")int eventid` allowing to take only integer but you provide some string (e.g `"Wedding"`) that can't hold by datatype `Integer`.

Comment: please post the rendered html of `jstl tags`, also how do you send `post request` to server? do you have a html form?

Comment: Is there any way to show name in <option> but passing id to controller?

Comment: Update your question original render value. not the jstl code. @R.Haque. After seeing your html code can decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's juste because you initialize your selection like that:

```
 <option  data-id="${eventName2.eventId}" value="${eventName2.eventName}">
```

In a html form the option component return to the server what you affect to the *value* field. You are affecting it a string and expecting an int.

```
<option  data-id="${eventName2.eventId}" value="${eventName2.eventId}">${eventName2.eventName}<option/>
```

Should do what you want.

Comment: Is it possible to show name in html but at backend send id to controller in case of dataList component? Actually i want a datalist here.

Comment: your solution is ok but i dont want to show id in html, because of security issue.

Comment: You could either use some Javascript to change the value on the submit but you would have to store the id you want somewhere so it's not a good solution for security. Or use an unpredictable business id that you can print in html (like the name if they are unique) and use the classic id only in backend.